# How to use another deployed smart contract functions?

Tags: solidity, import, function

What I want to do is deploy a smart contract with functions that other deployed smart contracts can call and get a response from.

How do I implement this? Is there any useful guides you guys know I could follow?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how you want the functions to be executed. If you wish to execute them in the context of your own contract, you should look into proxies => https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies

If you simply want to call the functions, you can do so using interfaces. Let's say you deploy contract A and want to call function called() from contract B:

```
interface contractB {
 function called() external returns(uint);
}

contract contractA {
 function callContractB(address addressOfContractB) view external {
   uint res = contractB(addressOfContractB).called();
 }
}
```